# Find the average of a given result set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My table looks like the one below. 
I am doing average for total table. I am getting 14. It is fine.

```
declare @Table table (Student Varchar(10), Score int)
    insert into @Table
    select 'A',10
    union all
    select 'B',20
    union all
    select 'A',10
    union all
    select 'C',20
    union all
    select 'B',10

select avg(cast(Score as float)) AvgScore from @Table

 AvgScore
 --------
  14

select Student, avg(cast(Score as float)) AvgScore from @Table group by Grouping sets(Student,())
    Student AvgScore
   ------------------
    A   10
    B   15
    C   20
NULL    14
```

If I do average (10+15+20)/3, I am not getting 14. 
How can I over come this? 
**Am I not doing mathematics correct?**
Can any give me brief explanation about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Total average is for all data so:

```
(10 + 20 + 10 + 20 + 10) / 5 = 70 / 5 = 14
```

Everything is ok. You try to calculate average on averages `(10+15+20)/3` which is nonsense from Math point of view.

Look at this example:

```
A - 1
A - 1
A - 1
A - 1
B - 20
```

Average is `(1+1+1+1+20) / 5` and **NOT** `(1+20)/2`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you reduce the information you have in the two steps of the calculation. Your original is a simple average.

[image: (10 + 20 + 10 + 20 + 10) / 5 = 70 / 5 = 14]

After your reduction you got:

[image: (10 + 15 + 20) / 3 = 45 / 3 = 15]

The problem you have is that the weight of each value is different. You got 2 values affecting `A`, two values affecting `B` but only 1 value affecting `C`. And this information, while important for calculating the average, is lost. What you need to do in addition is to get the proper average, is to store the weight of each average. Means the amount of source values. This would be:

```
Student    Value    Weight
      A       10         2
      B       15         2
      C       20         1
```

A weight is simply the count of values for each student. You can extract that easily in one query.

Now your final average calculation should look like this:

[image: ((10 * 2) + (15 * 2) + (20 * 1)) / (2 + 2 + 1) = 70 / 5 = 14]

Selecting the values you need should look like this I think:

```
SELECT Student, AVG(CAST(Score as float)) AvgScore, COUNT(*) Weight
FROM @Table
GROUP BY Grouping sets(Student,())
```

The rest of the path should be clear. Multiply weight and average values and divide it by the sum of the weight value.